# Laptop monitor is not working on boot

Tags: laptop, monitor, toshiba-satellite

In order to make my monitor work again I have to connect the laptop to a external monitor and then put the laptop in hibernate mode and then resume. After that the internal monitor works.

What is the problem and what should I do to get the internal monitor working normally?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You may have at some point disabled the internal monitor.

Comment: I never did anything like that.this problem is happening after fresh installation

Comment: can you try this command: cvt 1280 1024 60 and after to get the result output run: xrandr --newmode > {the new line mode result}